# How can I slightly delay the pop up of the task bar?

Tags: windows-xp, taskbar

Windows XP SP3

Many times as I head to the bottom of my desktop, I will slightly overshoot the target at the bottom and the task bar will pop up, hiding the target. I then have to move the cursor out of it so it retreats and then again try to access the target. Is there a way to add an interval, say, 1 second, to the task bar popping up so I can adjust to the target before the task bar covers it?

EDIT: as per my answer below, "What I ended up doing is just docking it on the LH side of the screen. There is no change in response but I don't go to that location so often so it's much better.".

Comment: This is one of many reasons I've never understood why you'd autohide your taskbar anyway...apparently I am weird though!

Comment: I do like the extra view of the desktop. Weird is as weird does - apparently someone agress with you.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Look here.](http://www.kellys-korner-xp.com/xp_tweaks.htm)  Specifically number 190!  The program on the right can add a timer to the taskbar popup.

Comment: +1. This looks good, but I am not literate enough to not feel worried about changing the registry. I'm going to wait a day or so to see other comments before acceptance. It looks like a great site you sent me to. Thanks.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is just docking it on the LH side of the screen. There is no change in response but I don't go to that location so often so it's much better. I'm going to accept the very helpful answer posted by @JNK. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Not weird at all... Mac OSX got it right a long time ago... SuSE also got it right... so with the growing and enlargement (heh!) of displays horizontally, you want to fill in your real state on the sides, hence, I do keep my taskbar on my right since long ago (since XP could not combine the icons and I could keep them all on the vertical taskbar).

The problem like yall know is that if the mouse pointer even breaths close to the taskbar it will pop up and get in the way, hence the delay on showing is a needed feature.

Tried several "add-ons" but they all got some kind of weird but that eventually show up... maybe it's time to try again... or Microsoft get it right... maybe...